# How to choose data from two components "select"?

Tags: angular

There are two "select" components.  The first component displays years, and the second, event names. The component displaying the year has the data type "number" (That is, the data is output in this form "2018"). And the second component, which has the names of events, must coincide by the year (only here the date is displayed in the format "Date", that is, has the form 2018-09-13). So, at the choice of the year (from the first component "select"), the second component should display information that matches the date. I have no ideas at all how to do it. Can you tell me how to implement this?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <label>Reporting period</label>
      <label for="favcity">
        <select id="favcity" name="select" >
          <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.years">
            {{year.years}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <label>Type of event</label>
      <label for="favcity">
        <select id="favcity" name="select"  >
          <option *ngFor="let typeEvent of typeEvents" [value]="typeEvent.name">
            {{typeEvent.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
     </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should add click event in the first select component and ngModel to store year value.

And click event calls changeEventList function with year value.
Then the changeEventList function filter the typeEvents with the year values.

And second component only shows filtered event list.

I added some pseudocodes and comments on your codes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <label>Reporting period</label>
      <label for="favcity">
        <select id="favcity" name="select" (click)="changeEventList(selectedYear)" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear" >  // <= add year variable and click event when you choose any option values.
          <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.years">
            {{year.years}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <label>Type of event</label>
      <label for="favcity">
        <select id="favcity" name="select"  >
          <option *ngFor="let typeEvent of typeEvents" [value]="typeEvent.name">
            {{typeEvent.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
     </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in the component.ts

```
changeEventList(year){
    this.typeEvents = originalTypeEventList.filter(event => event.value.indexof(year) !== -1 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case, i think, we should use the (ngModelChange) event instead (click) event.

```js
changeEventList(year){
    //you can filter the list of events  as you want 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <label>Reporting period</label>
      <label for="favcity">
        <select id="favcity" name="select" (ngModelChange)="changeEventList(year)" [(ngModel)]="year" >  // <= add year variable and click event when you choose any option values.
          <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.years">
            {{year.years}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <label>Type of event</label>
      <label for="favcity">
        <select id="favcity" name="select"  >
          <option *ngFor="let typeEvent of typeEvents" [value]="typeEvent.name">
            {{typeEvent.name}}
          </option>
        </select>
     </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```